# WPF - Using databinding to bind listbox of items and textboxes of detail

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying set up databinding as described in the title.

The problem I having is binding to a generic list.

Any examples out there.

I can't use BindingListCollectionView on a generic list so have to use
CollectionView.

The issue I am puzzled about is to add a new item
on click of Add button I add a new item to the
generic list and refresh the View. But if user 
does not follow through the list now has empty
item.

I know this is basic but how is that handled normally?

Malcolm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two questions here and I'll try to answer them step by step.

### Binding list of items with detail view

Given these ViewModel classes (imagine everyone implements `INotifyPRopertyChanged`):

```
public class DataView {
    public Item SelectedItem {get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class Item {
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Putting a `Data` instance into the `DataContext`, a minimal View might look like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Items="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.SelectedItem.Title}" />
</StackPanel>
```

### Adding new items

To be able to create a new `Item` without immediately adding it to the list, you might want to split off the newly created object into its own area. Visually you can either have it in a new pop up or integrated into the list, but actually it'll be only added to the list on the *next* try to add or acknowledge the parent dialog. At this point you can also verify whether the `Item` is valid enough to add it to the list.